# Hide subreport on ssrs preview(even dont want to show white blank tab).But show while exporting to excel

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I want to hide sub report on SSRS preview(even don't want to show white blank tab).But while exporting it should show sub-report too

Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick is using the multiple header Row of tablix.

For Example, If you have 1 Sub-report and 1 tablix report.

Steps1:

1. Insert a tablix
2. Delete the Detail row
3. Add another row below the header row (for subreport and tablix)
4. Resize the tablix row (rectangle inside the tablix row to make a fixed size, play with it)
5. Set the visibility property of each row in expression